# Actions on Google voice commands language

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

I built my Actions on Google project that works perfectly in English but when I tried tell something like "Turn on kitchen light" but in Polish the assistant said that this lights aren't configured yet. So I don't know what should I do. My AoG project has set localization to Poland, I can control my lights with Google Home app manually but through Google Assistant I can only speak in English. Please help me solve that. Am I missing something or am I just blind and don't see option which I should switch.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to control devices in a given supported language you will need support both on the project (AoG console) and the device on which the user issues the command. The language setting of the assistant on your phone or the google device (nest hub) might not be set to Polish language. There is also the possibility that the assistant might not be able to understand what you said, so you can try typing the command in Polish.

If you still experience the issue you can open a ticket on the Public Issue Tracker.